# Is there a way to move Component Tree back to right?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

Android Studio 2.2 has been launched in stable channel days ago and I saw that `Component Tree` is on left side instead of right.

As image suggests, the `Component Tree` is in the same window as palette:

[image: Component Tree]

Is there a way to move the `Component Tree` back to right (the same window as `Properties`) like earlier versions of Android Studio?

**UPDATE:** `Component Tree` is not a separated window anymore, so, it's part of the `Palette`, I'm looking for a way to detach the `Component Tree` from the `Palette` window and move it to right above `Properties` like earlier versions.

Comment: Have you tried to drag and drop the `Component Tree`

Comment: I'm out of luck, I can only drag&drop the `Palette` window, but not the `Component Tree` "subwindow" (subwindow because it's part of `Palette`).

Comment: Isn't SO a programming question-answer site? What's the question about programming here?

Comment: @Nordenheim: Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are [on-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Either Palette and the Component Tree moves together or not at all.

Comment: Both moves together, the `Component Tree` is inside `Palette` but splitted (sorry for my english)

Comment: I aswered my own question when Android 2.3 was launched, the new version finally solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Android Studio to 2.3. The latest version "2.3" detached "Component Tree" from "Palette" and you can move it.

If you updated Android Studio to 2.3, you will see the gear icon in Component Tree.

Before 2.3 was launched, the only way to solve this is submitting a bug report and wait to next versions to see the results.